# How can longitudinal and transverse waves be produced by hitting a vertical rod?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, oscillators

Would someone please give an intuitive explanation of this? I can still visualise an end of the rod getting compressed and thus transmitting a longitudinal wave, but how can a transverse wave be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strike the side of the rod, not the end.  This leads to a transverse displacement wave.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 is correct.  But for a solid you have surface waves.  A solid does not act like a fluid.  Fluids only support compression waves.  The solid has a crystal matrix that describes the reaction of the solid for all the different directions under influence of a force.  In particular there is the Poisson effect which loosely speaking states that if you compress a solid in one direction it will expand in the orthogonal direction.  Hence, if you strike a long rigid rod along its "longitudinal" axis you will excite waves in the orthogonal (transverse) direction.  This phenomena is also described in seismology with S and P waves.